# Throttling a POST with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to use [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Protocols/AFMultipartFormData.html#//api/name/throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize%3adelay%3a) to post an XML-RPC request. The AFNetworking library only offers throttling for form data ([`throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize:delay:`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Protocols/AFMultipartFormData.html#//api/name/throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize%3adelay%3a) on `AFMultipartFormData`).

How can I throttle regular `NSData` POST requests?

Here is my current code:

```
XMLRPCEncoder* encodObject = [[XMLRPCEncoder alloc] init];
[encodObject setMethod:function withParameters:[NSArray arrayWithArray:parametrs]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [afClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                      path:path
                                                parameters:Nil];

NSData* body = [[encodObject encode] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:bodyRequest];

AFHTTPRequestOperation* operationAf =
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:
    ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString* response = operation.responseString;
        NSLog(@"response %@,response");

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error%@", [error localizedDescription]);

    }];
```

Comment: Do you want to have a delay, do you want to limit the packet size or do you want to do both?

Answer (score 2):

`AFHTTPClient -multipartFormRequestWithMethod:...` is a method that takes a block with a proxy object that constructs a custom input stream for the associated request. `throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize` is a method on that block proxy object that is used to prevent buffer overflow over 3G networks, and is only really necessary when posting binary data like images.

Using `setHTTPBody:` overrides anything done with `-multipartFormRequestWithMethod:`, since it replaces the input stream constructed for the `NSURLRequest` with the `NSData` HTTP body. You should just do this, unless you actually need to send this as a multipart request (i.e. with image / file attachments).

If you do actually need multipart, use [-appendPartWithFormData:name:](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Protocols/AFMultipartFormData.html#//api/name/appendPartWithFormData%3aname%3a) in the constructor block.

Comment: yes but if i use only  [formData throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize:kAFUploadStream3GSuggestedPacketSize delay:kAFUploadStream3GSuggestedDelay]; and use the setHTTPBody the throttling will be done?

Comment: Please stop copying your comments on the closed GitHub issue.

Comment: @mattt: First...sorry  I didn't check all the comments/issues in github. This may be a dupe, but please let me know how to throttle if non-multipart? Is there a way to use as easier as it was in ASI (just call the methods and you were done)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `AFNetWorking` not support the throttling like `ASIHttpRequest`, it use the throttling only when sending binary file with  the `multipartFormRequestWithMethod` function :)